# Two NIC's 2 Internet Connections, 1 Windows Server 2008 RC2, Routing help required

Tags: windows-server-2008, nic

I have a Windows 2008 server and 4 other client machines on my home network. I have two internet connections. The main connection is setup with a home router and DHCP on that for all the clients on the network. The secondary connection is just a cable modem which is plugged directly into the server.

Local Area Connection: This NIC has an external IP and is connected to the Cable Modem.

Local Area Connection 2: This NIC has an internal IP (192.168.0.102) and allows access to all the internal computers. It also has internet access via the local router.

So here lies the problem, I want to use the Cable connection on the server for the internet traffic (so that the traffic for server/clients are seperated) but I also need to maintain local access. I am wondering how to make it so that all the internet traffic goes via that NIC because at the moment it goes through the local NIC.

As a secondary problem I would also like to forward the connection of one application used by the clients via the server and the cable/server internet because of poor routing for it on the main connection. This perhaps is something for another question though.

Thanks for any help you can offer me.

Regards

PJ

Comment: Do yourself a favour - forget it. Get a USD 40 Mikrotik 750 router and set it up there. I am a big fan of windows, but the stock routing mechanisms are just oprimtiive. They are really good enough for normal scenarios, but tey dont amke windows a powerfull router. Load balancing etc. is not on the list. Mikrotik is cheap, versatile and handles quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the server to use only one specific NIC for routing Internet-bound traffic, then you'll need to set the default gateway on that NIC and ***not*** set it on the other one (i.e. leave the field empty in the TCP/IP settings).

But you can't use both at the same time to balance Internet traffic, and you also can't do that on a per-application basis.

Comment: Now I just need to solve the routing problem for the application. It's a piece of VoIP software that I'm using on 2 of the Client PC's. The connection is very bad via the main connection so I wanted to make a proxy via the server to connect the software through my 2nd internet connection. It's the only application I want to do this with. At the moment I was just thinking of making an tunnel with putty and having a SOCKS proxy on the server but that seems exhaustive.

Comment: There's nothing native to the Windows operating system that could do what you want, sorry,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server applications being used, you might be able to specify that the server application use only one or specific network connection(s) (usually by its assigned IP). Most server applications that have this functionality will utilize "all" by default.

Comment: But if the NIC doesn't have a default gateway, it won't route traffic outside the local subnet; and you can't have two default gateways active at the same time.